# Sharepoint - running Sp.Web.currentUser Property

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I've been asked to look at a website. I have little html background but would like to access some SharePoint information with javascript. I opened up my console and tried:

`var value = SP.Web.get_currentUser();`, but it was an Uncaught TypeError.

`_spPageContextInfo.userId;` on the otherhand, works.

Any thoughts on how to get the first one working?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access the `Web.get_currentUser()` without loading first.

You can get `currentUser()` like:

```
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var oWeb = clientContext.get_web();
currentUser = oWeb.get_currentUser();

clientContext.load(currentUser); // prepare your query

clientContext.executeQueryAsync( // submit your query to the server
  function(){ // on success
    // var loginName = currentUser.get_loginName(); 
    // var userId = currentUser.get_id();
    // var userTitle = currentUser.get_title();
    // var userEmail = currentUser.get_email();

  }, function(){ // on error
    alert('Error: ' + args.get_message() + '\nStackTrace: ' + args.get_stackTrace());


});
```

Read more on here: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/128137